# Bash Regular expression for validating user accounts on Linux

Tags: linux, bash, validation, authentication

Looking for a simpler way to validate a user is requesting a password change for an account that is local and its a valid user ID format.

Valid user ID format is - `^[^a-zA-Z]*[a-zA-Z][^a-zA-Z]*t.*`

With the first character being upper or lowercase letter followed by the letter t followed by 4 alphanumeric characters for a total of 6 characters long.

Currently I am using the follow to evaluate an if else - `grep -Eow '\w{6}' /etc/passwd | grep ^[^a-zA-Z]*[a-zA-Z][^a-zA-Z]*t.* /etc/passwd`

```
if  grep -Eow '\w{6}' /etc/passwd | grep ^[^a-zA-Z]*[a-zA-Z][^a-zA-Z]*t.* /etc/passwd | grep -c "$cUname" $1 >/dev/null 2>&1; then
    echo -e "$linuxPassword\n$newPassword\n$newPassword" | passwd 
else
    echo "Account is not a local account on this machine or not a valid account"
fi
```

Is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: you need to quote the regular expression, since many of its characters have special meaning to the shell.

Comment: Your regular expression doesn't seem to be anything like the description you give of valid format.  If the first character has to be a letter, why do you start with `[^a-zA-Z]`. BTW, you can use the `-i` option to `grep` to make it case-insensitive, then you can write just `a-z`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```bsh
if [[ $cUname == [[:alpha:]]t[[:alnum:]][[:alnum:]][[:alnum:]][[:alnum:]] ]] &&
   grep -q "^${cUname}:" /etc/passwd
then
    echo "OK to change password"
else
    echo "$cUname: invalid username or username not found"
fi
```